# Facebook API infinite refresh

Tags: facebook, comments, refresh, infinite

I am using the standard commenting link and facebook api from github. For some reason today it decided that any page with comments will go into an infinite refresh. I added the line for Oauth 2 and it didn't solve the problem.

It has worked fine for several months, but the problem started today for no reason. Only happens when the person is logged into facebook.

Answer (score 0):

Most commonly I find this occurs because something in the session borked up.

So you have a partial connection and it loops to complete the connection but its expired and doesn't clean down properly.
Clearing your session cookies and restarting the session, and it not looping will indicate this is the problem and additional code will need to be added to detect a bad/partial session.

Possibly just a bug in the code, or a temporary problem with the Facebook API.